# Associating CakePHP HABTM models without a view

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm writing an import from CSV and have been able to successfully manually set data fields on a model in code by using the `$this->Book->set()` function and passing it a hash containing all of the `fieldName => value` pairings.

How do I create habtm associations in code? All the examples I've seen in the documentation are based on the `$this->data` returned from a form in the view. Because my data is coming from a csv file and not a view I can't use this!

So in the following example:

```
// Book habtm Tags
// Tag habtm Books

$this->Book->create();
$this->Book->set(
    array(
      'author' => 'tolkein',
      'title' => 'lord of the rings')
    );

$arrayOfTagIds = array(1, 5, 6);
// Do something with $arrayOfTagIds...
$this->Book->save();
```

How would I associate the $arrayOfTagIds with the Book?

Comment: As a side note: He's called Tolkien ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `set` to add data to the new entity and `save` to save it, use `create` and `saveAll`. In the example below, replace the `BookTag` model with the name of the model used in the relationship between books and tags. You'll also need to change `tag_id` to match the name of the field that represents the tag's id.

**Example:**

```
$book = array(
  'Book' => array(
    'author' => 'tolkein',
    'title' => 'lord of the rings'
  ),
  'Tag' => array(
    'Tag' => array(1,5,6);
  )
);

$this->Book->create($book);
$this->Book->saveAll();
```

Comment: Hi, I've edited the Tag array in your answer - I viewed the $this->data as submitted by the add action from the form; tweaked your code and it sprang in to life - thanks for your help!